# Why can I not create a foreign key for this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE News
(
    News_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Author nvarchar(50),
    Calender DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Contents nvarchar(20) NOT NULL, --store link to text file
    [Type_Id] int ,
    FOREIGN KEY ([Type_Id]) REFERENCES [Types]([Type_Id])
)
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [Types]
(
    [Type_Id] int,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY ([Type_Id])
)
```

I get this error:

> FK_News references invalid table Types

Can you help me?

Comment: In which order do you execute the two statements? Table Types needs to be created first before you can use it in a foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create `Type` table first and then `News` tables, as you are referencing foreign key from Type table to News table.

Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE [Types](
    [Type_Id] int,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY ([Type_Id])
)
```

Table2:

```
CREATE TABLE News(
    News_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Author nvarchar(50),
    Calender DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Contents nvarchar(20) NOT NULL, --store link to text file
    [Type_Id] int ,
    FOREIGN KEY ([Type_Id]) REFERENCES [Types]([Type_Id])
)
```

Since you have created News table first, drop it and recreate it. Or create both the tables without constraints and then alter both the tables with primary key ad foreign key receptively

Answer (score 3):

Since the `Types` table seems to be the primary one, you should create it first:

```
CREATE TABLE [Types](
    [Type_Id] int,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY ([Type_Id])
);
```

Then, create the `News` table, which has foreign keys referring to `Types` above:

```
CREATE TABLE News(
    News_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Author nvarchar(50),
    Calender DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Contents nvarchar(20) NOT NULL, --store link to text file
    [Type_Id] int ,
    FOREIGN KEY ([Type_Id]) REFERENCES [Types]([Type_Id])
);
```

It isn't possible to point a foreign key to a table which does not yet exist.